# VBA Validation List : Choices are not displayed

Tags: validation, vba, excel

I am currently developping some Excel Macros, and I have to use the cell validation.

I looked upon quite a lot of samples, which basically show  the same thing, but I can't get it to work properly.

Here is my code :

```
 Dim val As String: val = "this,is,sparta"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=val
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

But in the end, instead of having three choices ("this", "is" and "sparta") in the dropdown list, I only have one, equals to "This,is,sparta".

Did I miss anything in the configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want it to do so that's not the issue. There must be something else causing it not to work properly. Open a new workbook and try your code see if that works for you - it will help you identify if the problem is global or specific workbook related.

Comment: Indeed, I created a new Workbook, used exactly the same code, and it worked. 
What could have caused it to glitch in the previous one? I did nothing in it except testing the code above.

Comment: Now, that's quite a broad question which I don't think I am able to answer :/ just many combinations and possibilities.. be careful using the `:` operator specially in loops as VBA would not properly execute your code without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this self answer is just here to mark this question as resolved. see the comments on the very first post for any details.